# What is Jake trying to say before the pod closes completely?

Tags: avatar

Dr. Grace closes the pod in which Jake is lying down to
transform into his Avatar body:

> Dr Grace: Down. Just relax and let your mind go blank. That shouldn't
> be hard for you.
>
> Jake: Kiss the darkest part of my lily white...

What is Jake trying to say before the pod closes completely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dr. Grace has just insulted Jake:

> Just relax and let your mind go blank. That shouldn't be hard for you.

Basically, your mind is empty (you are stupid) so it should be easy to blank your mind.

Jake tries to comeback with an insult, but loses the last word of it:

> Kiss the darkest part of my lily white...

The last word is "ass."  He's saying not just "kiss my ass," he's going full on [Götz von Berlichingen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6tz_von_Berlichingen) and saying "lick my ass in the nastiest spot."